# bootstrap 4 how does one add top header and bottom header

Tags: bootstrap-4

[image: add table header top]

Hello how does one add a top table header just like in excel  example would be

top header     Person

bottom header  # Name Birthday

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
          <label></label>
        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th rowspan="2" >#</th>
            <th rowspan="2" >Name</th>
            <th rowspan="2" >Birthday</th>
            <th rowspan="2" ></th>


          </tr>
        </thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<caption>` tag. But if you are using bootstrap, caption would be positioned at bottom.

So you need to override caption CSS.

```css
caption {
  caption-side: top !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <caption>Caption</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">#</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Birthday</th>
      <th rowspan="2"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: is possible to add it in header basically it would be at top and the name, birthday, # would be at the bottom

Comment: Do you want to place column names at the bottom?

Comment: i mean i want the header column Caption at the top of the three column header is the possible ?

Comment: i don't want to use the caption tag but the th tag which is <th>Profile</th> then at bottom of them is <th>#</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Birthday</th>